# Airflow: DAG Runs not executing when expected

Tags: airflow

I would like my DAGs to be run at different time offsets.

I have set my DAG's start_date = pendulum.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 1, tz="UTC")
and the schedule_interval = '*/5 * * * * '

Since the start date is set to 1 minute after midnight I would expect the Runs to be run at 5 minute intervals of 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, etc... However, they are running at 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc...

Is this the expected behavior?
How can I offset the run time by 1 or more minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data interval and schedule are not related in that way.
Start_date is not a relative starting point for scheduler.
To achive running DAG at minute 1, 6, 11, 16, etc. you should set schedule_interval cron setup to `1/5 * * * *`